# Propositional Logic Proof using I.P. or C.P or rules of inference

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm attempting to solve a proof my professor asked. We are able to use any of the rules of inference, Indirect Proof or Conditional Proof. Every time I think am making progress I run into a brick wall. Here is the question.

1. $Q \lor (R \rightarrow S)$
2. $[R \rightarrow  (R \rightarrow  S)] \rightarrow (T \lor U)$
3. $(T \rightarrow Q) \land (U \rightarrow V)$
4. Conclusion: $Q \lor V$

I believe the easiest solution would be to attain $(T \lor U)$ from line 2 and then use as a Constructive Dilemma with line 3 but I'm really struggling to get past the $[R \rightarrow  (R \rightarrow  S)]$ part in order to get $(T \lor U)$. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

edit* I got by the previously mentioned part, but I am now struggling to get $(R \rightarrow S)$ from line one.

Translations:

- "$\supset = \rightarrow$"(if...then)
- "$\bullet = \land$"(and)
- ~ = $\lnot$(not)

[image: Rules of inference]
here is my work thus far. I have been trying any and everything for the past 4 hours and I have no idea where I am going from here. [image: my work]

Comment: You may find [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) useful for notation.

Comment: Please quote the rules of inference you're using. They are not the same in every system and every text -- just giving their names are not enough to enable people to help you; you need to show the actual rules.

Comment: What does the bullet in line 3 mean?

Comment: It is "and". I was simply using the format that was used in my book. They don't use the standard symbols, thank you for changing it to the general format.

Comment: You don't need to get (R→S).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Q∨(R→S)] assumption
2. {[R→(R→S)]→(T∨U)} assumption
3. [(T→Q)∧(U→V)] assumption
4. [~~Q∨(R→S)] 1 double negation
5. [~Q→(R→S)] 4 material implication
6. [~Q→((R∧R)→S)] 5 ∧ tautology
7. [~Q→((R→(R→S)] 6 exportation
8. [~Q→(T∨U)] 7, 2 hypothetical syllogism
9. (U→V) 3 simplification (this step isn't correct... we first have to use ∧ commutativity, and then use simplification.. shall I edit this to make this explicit, or is this clear enough?).
10. [~Q→(~~T∨U)] 8 double negation
11. [~Q→(~T→U)] 10 material implication
12. [(~Q∧~T)→U) 11 exportation
13. [(~Q∧~T)→V] 12, 9 hypothetical syllogism
14. [(~T∧~Q)→V] 13 ∧ commutation
15. [~(T∨Q)→V] 14 De Morgan
16. [~~(T∨Q)∨V] 15 material equivalence
17. [(T∨Q)∨V] 16 double negation
18. [T∨(Q∨V)] 17 associativity
19. [(Q∨V)∨T] 18 ∨ commutativity
20. (T→Q) 3 simplification
21. [~~(Q∨V)∨T] 19 double negation
22. [~(Q∨V)→T] 21 material implication
23. [~(Q∨V)→Q] 21, 19 hypothetical syllogism
24. [~~(Q∨V)∨Q] 23 material implication
25. [(Q∨V)∨Q] 24 double negation
26. [(V∨Q)∨Q] 25 ∨ commutativity
27. [V∨(Q∨Q)] 26 associativity
28. [V∨Q] 27 ∨ tautology
29. [Q∨V] 28 ∨ commutativity

Answer (score 2):

It turns out $R \rightarrow (R \rightarrow S)$ is actually equivalent to $R \rightarrow S$.  You can show this in a couple of different ways: use Material Equivalence twice, plus the associative and commutative laws for disjunction, or alternatively, use exportation.  (For the latter, though, you'd need some extra lines to justify turning $R \wedge R$ into $R$, since this doesn't appear to be one of your allowed equivalences.)

How to fit this into an overall solution, based on Indirect Proof: Suppose the desired conclusion is false, which by De Morgan and Simplification gives you both $\neg Q$ and $\neg V$.  By Disjunctive Syllogism you then obtain $R \rightarrow S$, and after applying the aforementioned equivalence followed by Modus Ponens, you arrive at $T \vee U$.  Simplifying the third premise and applying a Constructive Dilemma gets you to $Q \vee V$, a contradiction.

Comment: He has it : it is the Tautology n*18 : $p :: (p \land p)$.

Comment: You're right, I initially read that as a rule of inference rather than a rule of replacement.  Good catch!

Comment: That being the case, looks like I need to get $q \lor (R \rightarrow S$) out of line one and I'm confused on how to make that happen.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying @MauroALLEGRANZA. Could you perhaps make an answer so I could see exactly what you are saying? I'm trying everything but I can not get a grasp on how to solve this proof to save my life.

Answer (score 1):

We can "formalize" Dave's answer, using *Indirect Proof*  :

1) $\lnot (Q \lor V) \equiv (\lnot Q \land \lnot V)$ --- assumed [1] and using (DM)

2) $\lnot Q$ --- from 1) by (Simp)

3) $R \rightarrow S$ --- from premise 1. and 2) by (DS)

4) $(R \land R) \rightarrow S$ --- from 3) by (Taut)

5) $R→(R→S)$ --- from 4) by (Exp)

6) $T \lor U$ --- from premise 2. and 5) by (MP)

7) $Q \lor V$ --- from 6) and premise 3. by (CD)

but 7) contradicts 1); thus we have :

> 9) $Q \lor V$ --- by *Indirect Proof*, discharging [1].

*Conclusion :*

> > $Q∨(R→S), [R→(R→S)]→(T∨U), (T→Q)∧(U→V) \vdash Q \lor V$.

Comment: When doing exportation on my line 2, is it legal to just omit the other part of the statement. ie the $\rightarrow(T \lor U)$?

Comment: @MauriceAbney - no; I start from $R \rightarrow S$ and apply first Taut to have $(R \land R) \rightarrow S$ and **then** Export to get $R \rightarrow (R \rightarrow S)$ to be used **with** 2. for MP. In this way I can "detach" the consequent of 2., i.e.$T \lor U$. In this way, we have a *derivation* of $T \lor U$ form the assumption $R \rightarrow S$, i.e. $R \rightarrow S \vdash T \lor U$.